# How to find the value of x using the Pythagorean theorem of the following right angle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

How would i go on to find the value of x? or the height? I thought of using sin() but what angle would i take it? Also the directions said to use the pythagorean theorem? the base is in total 26? do i divide by 3? but the middle part isn't of the same size.

Comment: is the angel at P the same as the angle at L?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

We shall first find the horizontal length. Note that the left triangle and the right triangle are the same, just reflected over. Subtract $5$ from $26$ to get $21$ as the horizontal length of both triangles. Then divide by $2$ to get the horizontal length of one triangle. Then, use Pythagorean Theorem to determine $x$.